# How can I get numbers after and before decimal point?

Tags: python

I have number f = 93.7415

How can I get numbers after and before decimal point (`.`) using % opretor (I mean how to get 3 and 7)

I've tried something like this

```
f=float(input("Number: "))

print(f%10)
```

Comment: Where is the comma? Do you mean the decimal point? If so `int(f)%10` and `int(f*10)%10`

Comment: Yes I mean decimal point

Comment: Don't convert it to a `float`. Keep it as a string and use `split()`.

Comment: You can either do some math on the number or use some string operations or regex.

Answer (score 1):

With positive numbers, ,odulo with powers of 10 gives you the part of the number that is *after* that place. Integer division gives you the part that is *before*

```
>>> f = 93.7415

>>> int(f % 10 // 1)
 3

>>> int(f % 1 // 0.1)
 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo `%` operator

```
>>> s = '93.7415'
>>> f = float(s)
>>> int(f) % 10
3
>>> int(f * 10) % 10
7
```

`str.partition` which will split the string into two parts will require the number to have a decimal point

```
>>> s = '93.7415'
>>> before, _, after = s.partition('.')
>>> before[-1] # last character
'3'
>>> after[0] # first character
'7'
```

Finally regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '93.7415'
>>> m = re.match(r'.*?(\d)\.(\d).*?', s)
>>> m.group(0)
'93.7'
>>> m.group(1)
'3'
>>> m.group(2)
'7'
```